# Why I'm getting this error when debugging code in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having problem when debug code from netbeans. When I'm running it compile/run everything is ok. When I'm trying to debug code I'm getting this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class my.class.Main
Java Result: 1
```

As I wrote... runing is working fine :/

Comment: Sounds like you haven't selected the correct class as your main class.

Comment: I thought same way... but how compipiling and running is working fine.. ? Secend think is that i double-checked that. And selected class is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and I think that this **question is/was helpful**. 
As Netbeans 7.4 was release I had to go to:

Project properties -> Libraries -> Run and add there my JAR ( **dist/.jar** ).
After this was correct debug is working just fine.

Comment: Maybe true, but your title is not formulating your question, so for someone searching for solution it will be hard to find it.